# How do I remove API 26 from Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio did an update that caused it to use 26.0.0 of it's core support libs i.e. animated-vector-drawable, support-annotation, support-compat, support-core-ui, etc. In my project I have everything I can find set to use API 25. All my references for the dependencies are 25.3.1 and the buildTools are set to 25.0.3. targetSDKVersion is 25 as well. I've checked everything in File/Settings & File/Project Structure and I can't find any references to API 26, yet the studio keeps including these items which causes errors to show in the gradle file, and merged code to include items only available in API 26.

How can I make Android Studio use API 25 for this particular project?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.domain.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 50
        versionName "3.5"
        project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "App-" + defaultConfig.versionName + "." + defaultConfig.versionCode);
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        dev {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard false   // don't obfuscate
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    compile('com.uservoice:uservoice-android-sdk:1.2.+') {
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude module: 'httpcore'
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

[image]

[image]

**Update: ** contents of gradlew app:dependencies

```
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Project :app
------------------------------------------------------------

_debugAndroidTestApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
\--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
+--- com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
+--- com.android.support.test:rules:0.5
|    \--- com.android.support.test:runner:0.5
|         +--- junit:junit:4.12
|         |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|         \--- com.android.support.test:exposed-instrumentation-api-publish:0.5
+--- com.android.support.test:runner:0.5 (*)
+--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
+--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
|    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
+--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2.2
+--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3
|    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3 (*)
+--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
\--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2

_debugAndroidTestCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
\--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
+--- com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
+--- com.android.support.test:rules:0.5
|    \--- com.android.support.test:runner:0.5
|         +--- junit:junit:4.12
|         |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|         \--- com.android.support.test:exposed-instrumentation-api-publish:0.5
+--- com.android.support.test:runner:0.5 (*)
+--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
+--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
|    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
+--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2.2
+--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3
|    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3 (*)
+--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
\--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2

_debugApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.0.0
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.0 (*)
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:transition:25.3.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0
\--- com.uservoice:uservoice-android-sdk:1.2.+ -> 1.2.6
+--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.4.0
\--- oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2
\--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3

_debugCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.0.0
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.0 (*)
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:transition:25.3.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0
\--- com.uservoice:uservoice-android-sdk:1.2.+ -> 1.2.6
+--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.4.0
\--- oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2
\--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3

_devApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.0.0
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.0 (*)
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:transition:25.3.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0
\--- com.uservoice:uservoice-android-sdk:1.2.+ -> 1.2.6
+--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.4.0
\--- oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2
\--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3

_devCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.0.0
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.0 (*)
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:transition:25.3.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0
\--- com.uservoice:uservoice-android-sdk:1.2.+ -> 1.2.6
+--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.4.0
\--- oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2
\--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3

_releaseApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.0.0
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.0 (*)
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:transition:25.3.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0
\--- com.uservoice:uservoice-android-sdk:1.2.+ -> 1.2.6
+--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.4.0
\--- oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2
\--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3

_releaseCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.0.0
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.0 (*)
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:transition:25.3.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0
\--- com.uservoice:uservoice-android-sdk:1.2.+ -> 1.2.6
+--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.4.0
\--- oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2
\--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3


compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.0.0
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.0 (*)
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:transition:25.3.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 -> 26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0
\--- com.uservoice:uservoice-android-sdk:1.2.+ -> 1.2.6
+--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.4.0
\--- oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2
\--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3

SNIP

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

TIA,
Mike

Comment: Can you add the output of `gradlew.bat dependencies`?

Comment: I added in the output of gradlew app:dependencies. I had to cut a bunch out because we went over the 30k character limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `gradlew.bat dependencies` output:

```
\--- com.uservoice:uservoice-android-sdk:1.2.+ -> 1.2.6
+--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0 (*)
```

indicates that `com.uservoice:uservoice-android-sdk:1.2.6` relies on version `26.0.0` of the Support Library. You'll need to use an older version of the library if you want to continue to compile with API 25. (Using a `+` in a Gradle dependency is almost always a bad idea for this and many other reasons)

Of course, as per [Picking your compileSdkVersion blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd):

> It should be emphasized that **changing your compileSdkVersion does not change runtime behavior.** While new compiler warnings/errors may be present when changing your compileSdkVersion, your compileSdkVersion is not included in your APK: it is purely used at compile time. (You should really fix those warnings though — they were added for a reason!)
>
> Therefore it is strongly recommended that you **always compile with the latest SDK.** You’ll get all the benefits of new compilation checks on existing code, avoid newly deprecated APIs, and be ready to use new APIs.

You should really, really consider using the latest SDK.

Comment: That's IT! Thank you so much. I do intend to use the latest SDK in the next update. I was trying to hold off at least until the sources are ready and I have time to look at the code changes I want to do WRT Java 8.